# Only show significant correlations in heatmap

Tags: heatmap, correlation

I used the corr.test function to get the correlation values between to matrices and their p adjusted values.:

test <- corr.test(x, y, method="spearman", adjust="BH")

I have the correlation in test$r and the p adjusted values in test$p.adj. The rownames and colnames of both matrices are the same

I would like to create a heatmap where I only show correlations that pass the p.adj values of <0.5. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Will do. Sorry for this.  Figured it out though:  corrplot(cor, method = "square", type = "full", is.corr = FALSE, p.mat = pAdj, sig.level = 0.05, insig = "label_sig" )